# Pandas - Find unique values in the same column across multiple data frames

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two Dataframe with the same structure. I would like to find the unique values in the same column across these two Dataframe.

df1 structure:

```
emp_id, salary
101, 100
102, 102
```

df2 structure:

```
emp_id, salary
101, 100
201, 105
```

Expected output:

```
 emp_id
 101
 102
 201
```

Comment: you could concat the dataframes and get unique values on the enhanced emp_id column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `append` and `drop_duplicates`:

```
>>> df1.append(df2).drop_duplicates("emp_id")["emp_id"]
0    101
1    102
1    201
Name: emp_id, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin Nash , these is a solution for this task by using `pa.concat()`

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicate(keep='first')['emp_id']
```